# How Facebook autologin users in third party apps

Tags: facebook, api, security, oauth

In a common scenario, you login into Facebook (and many others services), then you go to another site and "login with Facebook". The api skips the user/pass step, sending user to authorize or directly to the app.

We always heard that an API should be stateless. The Facebook SDK only needs the API Key, I mean, there is no user information sended to API to identify that user.

So, how Facebook identify logged users? Does it use cookies?

Comment: Probably yes, they are using the cookies

Comment: Is there any security pattern to that?